# Getting "Handshake failed...unexpected packet format" when using WebClient.UploadFile() with "https" when the server has a valid SSL certificate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, http, https, webclient

I am trying to use WebClient.UploadFile with a HTTPS URL but I am ending up with

> "System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected
>   packet format"

The same code works perfectly fine with Http but the server that I am trying to hit has a perfectly fine ssl certificate. Here is anything relevant to the web call:

```
var url = WebServiceCommunication.GetProtocolName() + "..."; //turns out to be     "https://...
var wc = new WebClient();
//I am adding: 
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive, "...")
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "...")
we.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "...")

wc.UploadFile(url, "POST", filename);
```

Is the issue with any of the HttpRequestHeaders I am adding AND using https with those? Or am I missing a necessary header if I want to use https? Does anyone have any pointers as to why this would work with HTTP but NOT HTTPS when the SSL cert is valid?

Comment: Similar error in [System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected > packet format?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5178757)

Comment: This usually happen if you connect to a webserver using https but the web server is not set up for https. Try to use http:// instead of https:// in the URL.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have to make sure the port you are connecting to is port 443 instead of port 80.

Example of explicitly setting the port to be used in the URL:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://example.com:443/");
request.Method = "GET";
request.UserAgent = "example/1.0";
request.Accept = "*/*";
request.Host = "example.com";

var resp = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: You were spot on. I had hardcoded my web string as httpS://example.com:80, note the conflicting protocol-80 and the url starting with HTTPS. Rookie mistake.

Comment: or instead of having https you just have http

Answer (score 10):

You can also get this error if you're clueless like me and don't recognize that your web server project has crashed and is no longer running.