# Cannot download some https home pages using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, ssl, httpwebrequest

I'm just trying to download some site information, from various retail sites using C#, just the plain HTML of the home page. 
I have an issue with some sites which use **https**, some work fine while for others I get the following exception

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

The Inner Exception has

```
The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
```

I THINK it has something to do with TLS but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I've been all over Stack Overflow and the HttpWebRequest documentation.

Here's the sample code below I using to call the sites, and I'd be grateful if anyone had any insights on this, it's driving me crazy.

```
public HttpWebResponse GetWebResponse(HtmlVerb verb, Uri uri)
{

    var request = System.Net.WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
    request.Method = verb.ToString();
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0";
    request.Timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds;
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    request.ContentType = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

Kind Regards

Comment: Did you specify the port in the URI, as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895484/getting-handshake-failed-unexpected-packet-format-when-using-webclient-uploa ?

Comment: Try diagnosing what really happens using https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/netmon/p/downloads/ or https://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing this issue, I have found the following solution to work.
If you include the following lines of code at the start of your Application to initialise the application context, then these problem sites which use **https** now will download correctly.

```
private const string DisableCachingName = @"TestSwitch.LocalAppContext.DisableCaching";
private const string DontEnableSchUseStrongCryptoName = @"Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppContext.SetSwitch(DisableCachingName, true);
    AppContext.SetSwitch(DontEnableSchUseStrongCryptoName, false);
```