# System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format

Tags: c#, nginx, ssl

I'm trying to connect to a non-secure web socket server through WS, although when setting up a proxy with nginx I receive (on the WS server):

```
The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
```

This is handled as an `IOException`, and crashes the entire server.
stacktrace

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name ws.tunnel.cf;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/key.pem;

    server_name ws.tunnel.cf;


    location / {
         proxy_pass http://213.43.156.21:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

How exactly can I connect to my non secure web socket server, without making it `WSS`?

I am using Fleck as a package for the server.

Code for connecting:

```
const socket = new WebSocket('wss://ws.tunnel.cf');

socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    console.log('WS:open');
});
```

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21500778/3034273)?

Comment: @Xerillio Yes, see my nginx configuration, it enforces port 443 (SSL) on NGINX side.

Comment: That only works if the client can handle a redirect properly. You have yet to show the code from where you actually make the request

Comment: @Xerillio I have updated my question, there is no location block under port 80 server block, only 443 so it is impossible for it to even try connecting via port 80 (http).

Comment: My nginx knowledge comes a little short here, but it seems to me you are trying to pass an SSL connection from nginx to a backend application that doesn't handle SSL. So I think you either need to [SSL offload](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-ssl/) in nginx or configure your application to handle SSL/TLS connections

Comment: I am using `http` and not `https` with the proxy_pass, I don't believe I am passing a https connection? I could be wrong and will look into your suggestion.